# Silent return of SC command

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, service, silent

I'm trying to use a SC command to act as a verification that a program installed, but I would like the query to return silently. Is there any way to use this without it returning the service's status?

```
sc query MSSQL$Company
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
GOTO Good
) else (
GOTO Bad
)
```

Comment: `sc query MSSQL$Company > NUL`

Comment: Okay, sorry for such a simple question, then. What is the difference between /s and >null?

Comment: `>null` redirects messages to a __file__ with name `null` created in current directory. The name of the device is `NUL` (just one L and not two) and therefore `>nul` must be used to really suppress messages. The command `sc` with sc command `query` does not support a parameter `/s` (silent) as some other Windows command line commands support. You should read the [documentation of sc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754599.aspx) like you should do for any Windows console command you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Like Aacini mentioned in the comments, you should use `>NUL`. This will pipe the output of the command (any command by the way) to nothing and therefore silence it. An example code snippet would be:

```
sc query MSSQL$Company >nul
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
GOTO Good
) else (
GOTO Bad
)
```